# Can PHP be set to never cache a response, and always send something fresh to the page?

Tags: php, browser-cache

I have a webpage which pulls in an XML news feed and I don't want the page to cache it so that the XML feed displayed is most recent.

I tried this already so the cache is reset every 1800 seconds:

```
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=1800";
```

Didn't seem to work.

So what could I try to make the webpage auto refresh the XML in the PHP?

Comment: Are you concerned about browser-caching only? Or are you concerned about public caches like proxies, or caches on the server-side as well?

Comment: It looks like you're using some framework or some library to set the headers. Can you share which one?

Answer (score 1):

Usually in php I set these headers to avoid caching:

```
header( 'Cache-control: no-cache' );
header( 'Cache-control: no-store' , false );
header( 'Pragma: no-cache' );
header( 'Expires: 0' );
```

But it is not clear what are you doing. Are you calling a php page that outputs xml?

Client-side, I usally add a parameter (&time=actualtimestamp) to every request so that the browser doesn't cache it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, do a post request to obtain the XML. Post requests are not cache-able.

If you can not do a post request, add something unique to the query-info part the request 
URI, like the current time:

```
old: http://exmaple.com/data.xml
new: http://exmaple.com/data.xml?878621387
                                  ^ random number
```

---

I first read your question wrong and was concerned about that you want to prevent that a response of yours is being cached. Maybe it's still of use, so I leave it here:

In popular apps there often exists functions that set a bunch of headers to prevent caching. This is an example from the wordpress codebase:

```
  function nocache_headers() {
      @ header('Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT');
      @ header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
      @ header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
      @ header('Pragma: no-cache');
  }
```

It set the [`Expires`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) header to a date back in the past. So while being delivered, the document already expired or in caching terms is *stale*. Those documents should not be delivered by caches.

Then the [`Last-Modified`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29) header is set to the current time.

Then the [`Cache-Control`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) header is set to signal that caches [should not cache](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1) the response, [must revalidate](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.4) and should keep copies for a [maximum age of 0](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.4). This sounds a bit schizophrenic maybe (as if not cached, there can't be an age), but that's just to flood proxies and user-agents with data to make them stop.

Finally the [`Pragma`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.32) header is set to no-cache to prevent caching as well for HTTP/1.0 compatible proxies and user-agents (HTTP/1.1 clients normally make use of `Cache-Control`).

All these headers are explained in detail in the [Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1 RFC 2616 Fielding, et al. Section 14 Header Field Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) if you're eager to checkout the options available.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

This will prevent the page from being cached on a user's machine.

Answer (score 0):

How are you requesting the XML file? Probably either with cURL or url fopen, right?

Both these methods do not cache the response unless you specifically explicitly ask them to. So you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well probably you have not to set it in php/perl/.. you can also use the htaccess or apache configuration. One example i am using for htaccess: http://snipplr.com/view/4265/cache-control-with-htaccess-expires-by-type/